# Error when using this.template.querySelector()

Tags: lightning-web-components

I''m creating an LWC component, where I'll be creating buttons inside of a div. I'm using this.template.querySelector() and will be then using innerHTML and createElement.
However, I'm getting error with this.querySelector.
Below is the code :

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Phases">
        <div id="buttons">
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement , wire } from 'lwc';
import AccountPhases from '@salesforce/apex/AccountInfo.getAccountPhases'
export default class PhaseConfig extends LightningElement {
    lstPhases = [];
    sAccountName = 'Test Acct';
    renderedCallback(){
        AccountPhases({sAccountName : this.sAccountName})
        .then(result=>{
            this.lstPhases.push(...result);
            console.log('this.lstPhases : ' ,this.lstPhases);
            if(this.lstPhases.length > 0){
                this.createtabs(this.lstPhases);
                
            }
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            console.log('Error Occured');
        })
    }
    
    createtabs(lstPhases){
        console.log('createtabs : ' ,lstPhases);
        for(i=0;i<lstPhases.length;i++){
            let x = this.template.querySelector('buttons');
            console.log('x : ' ,x);
        }
    } 
}
```

If I comment the for loop inside of createtabs method, it works fine.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that for loop in createtabs method?

Answer (score 1):

May be 'this' inside loop is referring to block instance. Try below method instead:
createtabs(lstPhases){
let self = this;
for(let i=0;i<lstPhases.length;i++){
let x = self.template.querySelector('buttons');
console.log('x : ' ,x);
}
}

Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define `i` in the for loop.

```
  for(let i=0;i<lstPhases.length;i++){
            let x = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="buttons"]');
            console.log('x : ' ,x);
   }
```

and use data-id instead of id

```
  <div  data-id="buttons">
  </div>
```